# Set a default for tikz decoration marking distance from the line

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following MWE draws a line with a label above it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[inner sep=0pt, above=3pt] {$x$};}
        }]
        \draw[postaction=decorate] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but is there a way to set a default for that number `3pt`? What I want is that

- if I change `above=3pt` to `below` I will get the label 3 points below the line, because the default is 3pt.
- if I change `above=3pt` to `below=10pt` I will get the label 10 points below the line.

It's important to do this in a way that won't unnecessarily increase the bounding box, so just changing the `inner sep` wouldn't work for me.

This is for a library I'm writing and will all be wrapped up inside a command, so I could probably do it with string processing if needed, but it seemed like the sort of thing where tikz would provide a way to do it.

Comment: I think, something like `above/.default=3pt, below/.default=3pt` is what you're looking for. This would set `above` equal to `above=3pt` (and the same for `below`). But I don't quite understand where you would like to change this key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you're after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[
        above/.default=3pt,
        below/.default=3pt,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[inner sep=0pt, above] {$x$};}
        }]
        \draw[postaction=decorate] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code will default to `above=3pt` if you add the option `above` (and the same for `below`), but you can always override this for example with `above=10pt`.

I am unsure, however, how the final code should look like. But I leave this for you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you, yes, this works. I'll need to add defaults for left, right, above left, etc. as well, but that's no big deal.